# How can i send a string from one android to another over internet

Tags: android

I want something similar to Facebook messenger and
I don't have much knowledge about web servers,can i use them?
It should be like 
I accept on String from user and then upload it to my server and program the server to send it to other device and the other device gets notified by a background service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create something similar to Facebook messenger, you could do a lot of things.

Just to start, in my opinion, a [Serverless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_Framework) service. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) could be your solution or [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) (or any other service). It has a Push notifications and database where to store that Strings.

**Firebase Cloud Messaging**

*Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably deliver messages at no cost.*

*Using FCM, you can notify a client app that new email or other data is available to sync. You can send notification messages to drive user reengagement and retention. For use cases such as instant messaging, a message can transfer a payload of up to 4KB to a client app.*

**Firebase Realtime Database**

*The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database. Data is stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every connected client. When you build cross-platform apps with our iOS, Android, and JavaScript SDKs, all of your clients share one Realtime Database instance and automatically receive updates with the newest data.*

---

Other way is open a socket in your Android app and handle all the events. I recommend you [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) to do that.

You could use node.js in your server to create a [socket server](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and use the [Android client](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/).

http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/